# Why can’t connect to my school's servers from my hospital’s network when I was able to connect from my hotel’s network?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ssh, putty, winscp

I'm a college student studying software engineering, and right now I'm in the hospital, but I'm still trying to do my schoolwork. The semester is almost over, so I really can't afford to fall behind. For some reason, I can't connect to my school's Linux Lab with either PuTTY or WinSCP on my Windows 10 laptop. They both say the connection has timed out.

The hospital's guest WiFi network is public, but I don't think that's the problem since I was able to connect from a public hotel network without a problem a few days ago.

The starting code for my assignments is located on my school's Linux Lab, so I can't do them unless I can get that code somehow. Does anyone know of anything I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Hotels typically have very different (read lax) security and/or policies than institutions. And "guest WiFis" are typically very limited no matter where they are.

Comment: I have connected to the Linux Lab from outside the network before. I'm an online student, and my school lets their students remotely access the Linux Lab with SSH and SFTP. This is the first time I've had problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your school probably has some sort of [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) service available. VPN will create an encrypted tunnel between your machine and your school's servers. Try connecting to their VPN service and then try to SSH in. VPN connections will often be allowed where SSH won't.

Comment: See also *"Answers don't have to be exhaustive or infallible, they just need to try to answer the question. It's perfectly fine to post an answer saying, for example, "I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but if it's X, you can solve it by doing Y."* in [this meta A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/302572)

Comment: I know what a VPN is, but if my school has one, I don't know about it.

Comment: You don't need to use your schools VPN - you can use any VPN which will bypass the hospital firewall restrictions